# Preventing active OS fingerprinting with iptables

Tags: network, firewalls

I'm studying network security on my own and I have a few basic theoretical questions here.

Would dropping every incoming packet at the network layer be enough to prevent active OS fingerprinting? I guess this could be done with iptables, is that right?
I also guess that, if done this way, opening any port would be enough to enable fingerprinting once again, is this correct?
Finally, is there a less restrictive way to defend against OS fingerprinting? If not in general, at least against a certain implementation like nmap's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS fingerprinting, as you described, uses the network traffic characteristics of the OS. Some utilities exist to alter the defaults in order to mask the type of OS you use.

Dropping all incoming packets would work against fingerprinting attempts made by initiating new traffic from the outside, but not against fingerprinting attempts made by the destinations that you initiate traffic to. Opening a port to respond to initiated traffic would allow that type of fingerprinting.

You could proxy all traffic through another OS, thereby masking the traffic with the other OS.

The bigger question to ask here is "why do it at all?" Security by Obscurity has a place in a defence posture, but it is not meant to be a protective measure, but simply to raise the bar a little on automated attacks. If you have proper security in place, masking your OS networking defaults isn't going to gain you much. I would spend far more time on more fundamental defences than trying to confuse an OS fingerprinter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To answer your question, well, this is just theoretical. It is not that I have a network to defend, it was mere curiosity. I wanted to know how it could be done if I ever needed to, I'm just learning here. In fact, I learned quite a bit from your answer. I like the idea of routing through a proxy, and I did not think about untrusted hosts that I initiate a connection to. About the security by obscurity part... well, I think that knowing what OS the target is running can be very useful to an attacker. Of course, I know there are far more important things to secure first.

Comment: Glad I could help! Knowing the OS can give an attacker useful info, but the goal of a defender is to have a good defence even if the attacker already knows everything. The fact that an attacker has imperfect knowledge is supposed to be a bonus, not a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

`iptables`, as the name suggests, works at the Internet Protocol layer (OSI: network layer) and could drop any incoming packet.

But there are some ways of "talking" to that OS at the lower, link layer:

- You can ask it for the MAC address and that might tell you something about the hardware and in turn software running it. A Samsung OUI is more likely to be a phone than there are specific Samsung OUI sets for Android phones.
- Deauthenticating the target from the a wireless network and watching it authenticate and potentially use DHCP might give further clues about it.
- A device that talks tunnelling protocols like PPP, PPTP, L2TP or layer 2 discovery protocols might only have a few specific OSes.
- The latency in ARP responses might indicate if it's an embedded slow device or a multipurpose fast one.
- Different OSes might act differently under a layer 2 flood and respond differently, if at all, to ARP requests.

Controlling ARP interaction can be done with the `arptables` utility.